# AngularJS, mailto passing current URL but without parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From my controller I need to share by email the current URL. I succeed doing it using:

```
$window.location.href
```

And with

```
$window.open("mailto:"+ emailId + "?subject=" + subject+"&body="+message,"_self");
```

I can correctly open the email client with the URL. My problem is that in console.log I can see the entire URL including the parameters, but in the email body not! Do you know why and how to solve? I guess security reasons right?

Solved from the comments below using the statement below but don't know how to make it clickable:

```
encodeURIComponent(url variable)
```

Comment: are `subject` and `message` URL-friendly? Are they encoded?

Comment: no...ok Jeremi, will check this!

Comment: @JeremyThille the URL is in the body and the variable message is just the $window.location.href..

Comment: yes but all this contains special characters (slashes...) that must be encoded with `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Jeremy you solved, with encodeURIComponent($window) etc is working. Thanks a lot! If you answer I flag it as solved...